# UWP Mapcontrol - Binding to collections of different MapElement and arranging them in layers

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I am displaying several different types of MapElements on the UWP MapControl and regularly updating their position, size, etc. as the user works with the map. Currently I do all of this in code. I'd like to find a convenient way of binding multiple different collections of MapElements, as then I'd have less code to maintain.

With Creator's fall update 16299 Microsoft has added the [MapElementsLayer class,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelementslayer) and It appears to be perfect for the job, but I cannot get it to work. 
When I bind it to an ObservableCollection of MapElement3D I don't see any of them appear on the map. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Maps:MapControl 
        x:Name="MainMap"           
        MapProjection="Globe"
        ZoomLevel="15.5"

        <Maps:MapElementsLayer x:Name="Cars"  MapElements="{x:Bind _VehicleCollection, Mode=OneWay}"  />

 </Maps:MapControl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to find a convenient way of binding multiple different collections of MapElements, as then I'd have less code to maintain.

As you mentioned, map layering APIs can help represent a collection of map data to which you can bind data. Unlike the existing `MapControl.MapElements` API, this can be used to manipulate groups of elements independently as a unit or to designate a joint purpose.

But you need to bind data collection to the map using **`MapControl.Layers`**. This is something that you can't do by using the `MapElements` collection. More details about map layering APIs and how to do please reference [Working with layers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#working-with-layers). For example:

```
<Maps:MapControl
    x:Name="myMap"
    Layers="{x:Bind ViewModel.LandmarkLayer}"
    MapProjection="Globe"
    MapServiceToken="Your token" />
```

You need to bind layers collection to `MapControl.Layers` property.

Comment: OMG! Thank you, it's really simple, I just somehow couldn't find the right page in the documentation!

Comment: I would like to add that  is only the way to get working `MapControl` properly. Thank you @Sunteen Wu!